# Django refuses to save the date shown on django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus?

Tags: python, django

In my Django (1.11.5) project I use [django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus](https://github.com/monim67/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus) application for `DateField` in `Profile` model. When user submit form nothing happens and I don't understand why Django refuses to save the date shown on form. How to fix it?

**models.py:**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=False)

   @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
   def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
       if created:
           Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
       instance.profile.save()
```

**forms.py:**

```
# "django-user-accounts" application
from account.forms import SignupForm as BaseSignupForm
# "django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus" application
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus import DatePickerInput

class SignupForm(BaseSignupForm):
    birth_date = forms.DateField(widget=DatePickerInput())
```

**views.py:**

```
# django-user-accounts application
from account.views import SignupView as BaseSignupView

class SignupView(BaseSignupView):
    form_class = SignupForm

    def generate_username(self, form):
        pass

    def after_signup(self, form):
        self.create_profile(form)
        super(SignupView, self).after_signup(form)

    def create_profile(self, form):
        profile = self.created_user.profile
        profile.birth_date = form.cleaned_data["birth_date"]
        profile.save()
```

Comment: Your `BaseSignupForm` deals with a `User` model, so Django does not connect that field with the profile. You do that manually `SignupView`.

Comment: What you suggest? Create `SignupView` which inherit from `forms.Form`? In that case what I need to set in `views.py`? Which `form_class` must be. I am little bit confused.

Comment: I use this: https://github.com/pinax/django-user-accounts/blob/master/docs/usage.rst#customizing-the-sign-up-process

Comment: When I add to `DatePickerInput` widget format of the date like this `format: "yyyy-mm-dd"` it raise error: `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "birth_date" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (7, null, null, , , , , , 1, 2, 2, 0, null, null, 7).` It seems like birth_date field has null elements. Do you have any ideas about that?

Comment: Finally I found solution. In model I change `DataField` to `blank=True`. After that change form save everything correct.